How to Automatically Install a .mobileconfig Profile from a String in iOS Using Swift?
I have a .mobileconfig string sent by my server. If I configure it for IKEv2 VPN, it works.
When I manually download and install the .mobileconfig file, everything works fine. However, I cannot do this manually for our users. Is there a programming way to achieve this?
I tried generating a temporary file from the .mobileconfig string and opening it with Safari, but it didn’t work.
Similarly, I tried saving the temporary file to local storage, but I don’t want users to manually install it.
What I want is a way to create a temporary file and install it automatically in the simplest way possible.
To establish a secure VPN connection, I need to add the CA certificate to the Keychain, but I’m not sure about this. Still, I added the CA payload content from the .mobileconfig file to the Keychain (I hope I did it correctly). If this step is sufficient (a bit of help, please), I understand that I won’t need to perform the other steps.
I’m a bit confused about this. Could it be that NEVPNManager does not allow direct manipulation with CA certificates?
If that is true, how can I install the mobileconfig file programmatically with Swift without tiring the user?

Not possible at leat on nonjailbroken devices. Too insecure.

You can remotely install configuration profiles through MDM, but users still will need to install configuration profile with MDM parameters manually.

https://developer.apple.com/documentation/devicemanagement/configuring_multiple_devices_using_profiles
